# Performance of GridView vs DataList vs Repeater vs ListView

Tags: asp.net, performance, controls, comparison

I have read some articles about this matter... and it seems that the Repeater is the one with best performance as explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose).

I know that the GridView is the heaviest of them all, and that it weights a lot in the ViewState. So the DataList has been the "best" option for some situations.

But how about Datalist performance vs ListView?

Also, the GridView has a Pager already built in... and it seems that the ListView has one to.
But if it create a pager for the DataList... will it become heavier than the GridView?
And how about DataList + Paging vs ListView with Paging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

performance
reperter > datalist > gridview

simple control High-performance

Comment: Thx for the comment. But how about the ListView? Where does it fit in therms of performance? Before the datalist? before the gridView?