# How To Convert AJAX Treeview To Linkbuttons?

Tags: ajax, treeview, asplinkbutton

I need some advice regarding conversion of an AJAX `TreeView` control to a `LinkButton`.
Why? To make the ASP.NET page lighter. Currently, when the `Nodes` of the `TreeView` is selected, records related to that node are displayed in a grid. This implementation makes the page heavy. So we decided to changed this to `LinkButtons`.

I just want know what are the things I need to do, consider, or is this a good idea? Honestly, whether this is a good or bad idea, I still need to do this.

My initial understanding is that this will turn out like a list `ex: bullet list`.

Comment: Ok I think I got a clue how to do this, by using a repeater with linkbuttons. But the problem is that I'm not familiar with this control. There will be 3 layers of linkbuttons (Parent linkbutton, child linkbuttons, sub-child linkbuttons), is this possible>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is based on your comment and builds on the answer provided in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742919/how-to-create-a-nested-linkbuttons-inside-a-repeater/6754987#6754987).

The following example uses a ListView instead of a Repeater.  ListViews are great because they'll give you much more flexibility over a Repeater.  Moreover, as you can see in the sample code below, binding the nested/child ListView and binding the nested/grandchild ListView can all be done declaratively *without any code-behind*.

**Example of what the following code will produce**

[image]

**ASPX**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvw">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>    
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name")%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvw2" DataSource='<%# Eval("Children")%>'>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name")%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvw3" DataSource='<%# Eval("Children")%>'>
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                                </ul>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name")%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:LinkButton></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**C#**

```
lvw.DataSource = personList;
lvw.DataBind();
```

As you can see, in the C# code, I've created a list of "Person" as follows.  Each Person object has a list of child Person objects and aach child Person object has a list of child Person objects.  By creating your objects in this manner, binding the ListView is really as simple as I've shown.  Use the Person object below to run a quick sample so you can see for yourself.

**Person object**

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

For your test, you can create a Page_Load method as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
        Person person1 = new Person() { name = "Child 1" };
        Person person2 = new Person() { name = "Child 2" };
        List<Person> childPersonList1 = new List<Person>();
        childPersonList1.Add(person1);
        childPersonList1.Add(person2);
        Person person3 = new Person() { name = "Person 1" };
        person3.Children = childPersonList1;
        personList.Add(person3);
        Person person4 = new Person() { name = "Child 3" };
        Person person10 = new Person() { name = "Grandchild 1" };
        Person person11 = new Person() { name = "Grandchild 2" };
        Person person12 = new Person() { name = "Grandchild 3" };
        List<Person> grandchildPersonList1 = new List<Person>();
        grandchildPersonList1.Add(person10);
        grandchildPersonList1.Add(person11);
        grandchildPersonList1.Add(person12);
        person4.Children = grandchildPersonList1;
        Person person5 = new Person() { name = "Child 4" };
        List<Person> childPersonList2 = new List<Person>();
        childPersonList2.Add(person4);
        childPersonList2.Add(person5);
        Person person6 = new Person() { name = "Person 2" };
        person6.Children = childPersonList2;
        personList.Add(person6);
        Person person7 = new Person() { name = "Child 5" };
        Person person8 = new Person() { name = "Child 6" };
        List<Person> childPersonList3 = new List<Person>();
        childPersonList3.Add(person7);
        childPersonList3.Add(person8);
        Person person9 = new Person() { name = "Person 3" };
        person9.Children = childPersonList3;
        personList.Add(person9);

        lvw.DataSource = personList;
        lvw.DataBind();
    }
```

See the following StackOverflow question to learn more about the differences between a Repeater and a ListView: [Repeater, ListView, DataList, DataGrid, GridView ... Which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose)

Comment: My pleasure.  Was the code able to help or are you still having problems?

Comment: One more thing Alison, I just want to ask if I use a ListView in my page, will it make the page lighter? Making the page lighter is the main goal that's why my first choice was a simple nested repeater... But if the difference between a ListView & Repeater in terms of lightness in a page is minimal, I think I'll go with your suggestion.

Comment: By the way, one thing I liked the most in the ListView is the output of the ListVew because it is already bulleted and more presentable..

Comment: @furanzu: The biggest advantage of the ListView over a Repeater is the ease-of-use.  Trying to build a 3-level nested solution using a Repeater would be a nightmare, in my opinion.  Is the ListView lighter than the Repeater?  In this case, it probably doesn't matter as they'll both be light.  Which one will you enjoy/prefer to use?  Definitely the ListView.

Comment: @furanzu: Glad it helped.  If you're not searching for more answers then you can click the checkmark to left of this answer to mark it as "Correct Answer".  I noticed that you haven't done this for any of your other questions.  Marking a question as "correct" gives the person that answered the question some points, it also encourages others to answer more of your questions, and it lets other people with the same/similar problems find helpful answers/advice.  It's good karma and it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Hi Alison! Sorry I didn't know that... I thought clicking the up arrow in you main answer is enough.. thanks for informing me..

Comment: By the way, do you know how can I increase the item spacing in the listview? I'm googled it but found nothing...

Comment: A bit of CSS applied to the billeted list should do the trick.

Comment: @furanzu: I just realized that you still might not "get" how to mark a question as "answered".  Take a look at the following link and see the top answer.  It explains everything: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work .  Did you ever get your list styles sorted out?

Comment: Hi Alison! Sorry I misunderstood what you said on how to mark you answer as answered.. Now I think I got it right by clicking the checkmark of you answer. There are only 3 minor things that I need to do in my ListView right now:  
1. Adjust item spacing.  
2. Remove underline for Linkbuttons
3. Enable underline of a selected Linkbutton

I don't know if these items are possible, if you have an idea please share it with me.. Thanks!

Comment: It is definitely possible and should be easy to implement. I can't do a test today but I will post sone updated code hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: In disabling the underline in my LinkButtons, what I did is set both asp:LinkButton's CssClass="NoUnderlineLinkClass" and defined it in my css file like a.NoUnderlineLinkClass:link { text-decoration: none;} but it is still not working. I think there is something wrong here.

Comment: In adjusting the spacing in my LinkButtons, what I did is set the style's margin-bottom and margin-top properties and it works.. Regarding finding the selected LinkButton in my ListView, currently I'm using just a FindControl method in the OnItemCommand event to know the selected LinkButton. I think it is much better if I could use the ListView.SelectedItem or SelectedValue or something...