# How To Create A Nested LinkButtons Inside A Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, linkbutton

I need to create a nested linkbuttons in a asp.net page that looks like a treeview, but all are linkbuttons. Example is shown below:

```
ParentLinkButton1
    ChildLinkButton1
    ChildLinkButton2
    ChildLinkButton3
ParentLinkButton2
    ChildLinkButton1
    ChildLinkButton2
ParentLinkButton3
ParentLinkButton4
    ChildLinkButton1
```

I really don't know how to do this. Based on my research this can be done using repeated control but I don't know how to do that... Please if you can teach me step by step...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example uses a ListView instead of a Repeater.  ListViews are great because they'll give you much more flexibility over a Repeater.  Moreover, as you can see in the sample code below, binding the nested/child ListView can all be done declaratively *without any code-behind*.

**Example of what the following code will produce**

[image]

**ASPX**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvw">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>    
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name")%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvw2" DataSource='<%# Eval("Children")%>'>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name")%>'><%# Eval("Name")%></asp:LinkButton></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**C#**

```
lvw.DataSource = personList;
lvw.DataBind();
```

As you can see, in the C# code, I've created a list of "Person" as follows.  Each Person object has a list of child Person objects.  By creating your objects in this manner, binding the ListView is really as simple as I've shown.  Use the Person object below to run a quick sample so you can see for yourself.

**Person object**

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

For your test, you can create a Page_Load method as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
        Person person1 = new Person() { name = "Child 1" };
        Person person2 = new Person() { name = "Child 2" };
        List<Person> childPersonList1 = new List<Person>();
        childPersonList1.Add(person1);
        childPersonList1.Add(person2);
        Person person3 = new Person() { name = "Person 1" };
        person3.Children = childPersonList1;
        personList.Add(person3);
        Person person4 = new Person() { name = "Child 3" };
        Person person5 = new Person() { name = "Child 4" };
        List<Person> childPersonList2 = new List<Person>();
        childPersonList2.Add(person4);
        childPersonList2.Add(person5);
        Person person6 = new Person() { name = "Person 2" };
        person6.Children = childPersonList2;
        personList.Add(person6);
        Person person7 = new Person() { name = "Child 5" };
        Person person8 = new Person() { name = "Child 6" };
        List<Person> childPersonList3 = new List<Person>();
        childPersonList3.Add(person7);
        childPersonList3.Add(person8);
        Person person9 = new Person() { name = "Person 3" };
        person9.Children = childPersonList3;
        personList.Add(person9);

        lvw.DataSource = personList;
        lvw.DataBind();
    }
```

See the following StackOverflow question to learn more about the differences between a Repeater and a ListView: [Repeater, ListView, DataList, DataGrid, GridView ... Which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing a repeater inside of a repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptParentLinkButtons" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton id="lnkParentbutton" runat="server" Text="<% Eval("ParentText") %>" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater id="rptChildLinkButtons" runat="server" DataSource='<% Eval("ChildElements") %>' >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton id="lnkChildButton" runat="server" text="<% Eval("ChildText") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then in the ItemDataBound events you can set the data source for the child repeater and bind it.

Feel free to ask for any clarifications.  i don't want to write the whole thing for you.

EDIT:

To bind the parent, you would want to use Page Load or some other page event to add the datasource to the outer repeater and then bind it.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            rptParentLinkButtons.DataSource = myParentItemCollection;
            rptParentLinkButtons.DataBind();
        }
```

And then you have 2 options, wither the way I showed it in the asp above by accessing your databound object using the eval, or by using the parent's ItemDataBound event.

```
void rptParentLinkButtons_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

          // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

          Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptChildLinkButtons");
          // Set the source of the child equal to a collection on the parent object for it to make the child links.
          childRepeater.DataSource = myParentItemCollection[e.Item.ItemIndex].childElements;
       }
```

The above code is not perfect, but it should get you a good idea on how to get the rest of the way,

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I know this sound stupid but can you show me how to bind data to this 2 repeaters?

My guess is that I need to bind the data in the rptParentLinkButtons_ItemDataBound and rptChildLinkButtons_ItemDataBound. My data will come from a List...

Comment: Edited with more info for you.