# select data from table and display them in a label with checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I retrieved my data from table and put it in a label. Now I want for each row to generate a checkbox. How can I do that? so..

```
                          option1..checkbox1
                          option2..checkbox2....
```

This is my code for obtaining the data:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["erp"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string intero = "Select * from judete";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(intero, con);

            SqlDataReader rdr;

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {


                Label1.Text +=rdr[0] + "" + rdr[1] + "<br/>";
            }

            rdr.Close();
            con.Close();
```

I'm using C# in an asp.net web application

Comment: The easiest would be to use any databound webcontrol like `GridView`, `DataList`, `ListView` or `Repeater`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx Here are  comparisons: http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/a/139308/284240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your second question
Add this code in your previous code

```
cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged);
```

And then create a new method like this

```
void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something 
}
```

Comment: you can edit your current answer to post this new addition. Also you need to give unique IDs to the checkboxes

Comment: and inside this method I'm gonna make my query?

Comment: but how do I know which checkbox is checked?

Comment: means... You will be clicking a check box

Comment: yes..but  when I press the checkbox USA I want to bring the cities from USA..or if I have Germany the cities from Germany..that's why I asked you how do I know whici checkbox is checked..

Comment: you need to give unique name to your checkbox or use CheckBoxList instead of checkbox and add event to each checkbox.

Comment: how can I give a distinct name in your example of creating checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

First add a Panel Control to your page. this is must and then use this code

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Label1.Text +=rdr[0] + "" + rdr[1] + "<br/>";
    CheckBox cb= new CheckBox();
    cb.Visible=true;
    cb.Width=300;
    cb.Text=rdr[1].ToString();
    Panel1.Controls.Add(cb);        
}
```

Hope this might work.

Comment: I want to ask you another thing..if I want that when I check a checkbox that is created other checkboxes with data from another table appear related to that checkbox.So: checkbox1 USA is checked 4 other checkboxes appear with 4 towns from USA.How can I do that?

Comment: You need to add EventHandler for that checkbox you create programatically

Comment: how can I do that? I don't know how to use EventHandler

Comment: check out the new answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) control.

```
    SqlDataReader rdr;

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    CheckBoxList1.DataSource = rdr;
    CheckBoxList1.DataBind();


<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxList1" 
           DataTextField=".. column to display.." 
           DataValueField="... column to use for values .." />
```

Comment: I'll correct or delete the answer, but please explain why the downvote

Comment: Someone was going through upvoting all the other answerers' posts and DVing many of the "competing" answers.