# How to do paging in repeater?

Tags: c#, repeater, asp.net-4.5

How to do paging for a table of 10 records to show only some of them at once.
The code behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        Rep_Bind();  
    }  
    private void Rep_Bind()  
    {  
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbbook",ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);  
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
        adp.Fill(ds);  
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;  
        Repeater1.DataBind();  

    }
```

And this is the html code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src='<%#Eval("bookimg") %>'height="50" width="50" />
                            <b>Title:</b><%#Eval("booktit" )%><br />
                            <b>Author:</b><%#Eval("bookauth") %><br />
                            <b>Publisher:</b><%#Eval("bookpub") %><br />
                            <b>Price:</b><%#Eval("bookprc") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Now i want linkbuttons for next and prev. which shows next and previous records.So what should i do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a DataPager control.

Not sure you can get paging with a Repeater out of the box though. You'll require quite a bit of work to get it working. Check this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)

You might want to use a ListView instead.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src='<%#Eval("bookimg") %>' height="50" width="50" />
                                <b>Title:</b><%#Eval("booktit" )%><br />
                                <b>Author:</b><%#Eval("bookauth") %><br />
                                <b>Publisher:</b><%#Eval("bookpub") %><br />
                                <b>Price:</b><%#Eval("bookprc") %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
```

Comment: @user2069465 use the listview instead of the repeater. remove the repeater completely and modify your code behind to bind to the listview instead, i've used your itemtemplate to it should work without any issue.

Comment: but i want this through repeater??

Comment: @user2069465 I guess you should take a look at this link http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx :)

Comment: Of course pagination can be used with repeaters. search google or stackoverflow directly for pagination for repeater and you'll find an endless number of examples!

Comment: @lKashef I'm not sure you understand what I was trying to say .. by default, you can't get paging in a repeater .. you'll have to do some extra work to get paging on it. Can you provide details on how to do it without extra work? if you can, i'll gladly change my answer ..I don't mind learning something new :)

Comment: @scartag, well I'm sure you know the facts. However your answer can be misleading to beginners. Instead of saying that you can't get the pagination functionality and refer the guy to change the Data Control he's using (Repeater to ListView), In my opinion you should have clearly advised him that you can't get the functionality out of the box however it can be done with some extra work, and maybe if it's too complicated for him you can add the ListView option as an extra.

Comment: @scartag, I hope there are no hard feelings, I just think the question was about Pagination in Repeaters and your answer focused on ListView and added the important part in a comment.

Comment: @lKashef No hard feelings of course!! I just wanted to hear your point of view .. if you noticed  .. the OP accepted the answer because he went through the link i posted and saw what i meant .. Take a look at both controls .. very similar (item templates) and easy to change .. which is why i suggested the listview and provided a link to use a repeater if he preferred that.

Comment: @scartag I know how you feel, I also like to know why my post is getting a negative feedback. Repeater is different and far more light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose. 

I know the OP accepted the answer but he is clearly lost and new to the framework. however stackoverflow is not only about the OP it's about other thousands who search for the same question. so as I told you I think it makes only good sense to answer the question then offer an extra advice for the sake of the OP.

Comment: @lKashef Hi, I changed the answer based on your feedback ... Thanks

Comment: @scartag You're welcome and It was nice to meet a dedicated member to the community.