# Possible to have dynamic content with accessable controls in asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I really hope that someone can help, pointing me in the right direction. I'm still new to the more advanced features of asp.net / C#.

What i need is a div, in that div i would want some informations from the database. furthermore i want a textbox with a number and an arrow up and down to increase/decrease the amount in the textbox. And at last a button outside the div to submit the value.

Now the tricky part (for me), is that one div is not enough, I need one div for each "person" in the database. i can easily make that, but.. if i add it dynamically from the .aspx.cs file i am not able to access the value like : textbox1.text; because textbox1 does not exist in the code before it is created.

I have looked at listview and a repeater, but those seems more like they're for making lists, and i need more than that, as i need some functionally too.

[image: simple preview of the box i want duplicated]

The way i would do it now is to add the div by innerhtml. and then adjust the amount by a for loop which also inserts the information from the database which i got in an array. But as said, that doesn't really do the trick when i need to access the textbox and stuff.

Thanks in advance for just looking at it.

EDIT:

I'm not looking for at complete solution, i just want some directions.

Comment: In what way is this question _"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"_? I guess that the downvoter hasn't even read it fully.

Comment: All i'm looking for is someone to say: "Hey, that can be done by using a repeater" - as i'm not that experienced that i even know where to start looking or how.

Comment: You can add anything in a `Repeater` since it allows to add HTML or server side controls. So what i'd do is to create a custom `UserControl` with all controls in it that you need. Then you just need to drag this `UserControl` in a repeater's `ItemTemplate`. However, you could also do that with a `ListView` which has additional features like `Paging`. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose) a short summary of  ASP.NET web-databound controls.

Comment: Thank you!, just the kind of help i was looking for, as i'm here to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will asume by your post description that by asp.net you mean webForms. If you're new on asp.net development, you have to know that there are different development, in the past (but still very commonly used) you would use WebForms, now at days the trends are using asp.net MVC framework.

**now back to your question:**

in asp.net WebForms, you have your code defined in two sides: your markup (HTML code normally in a .aspx file) and your code-behind (c# or vb code normally in a .aspx.cs or .aspx.vb).

what I would suggest you to do, is to add your logic for retrieving data from your database in your page_load() function of your code-behind, with this data you would normally use a loop to read all your results and for each result you would create your div with your textbox inside (the trick is using native .net framework classes instead of inserting the HTML directly). a simple example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] personsIDs; //<-- this came from your database
    Dictionary<string, TextBox> textBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();

    foreach(string personID in personsIDs)
    {
        TextBox personTextBox = new TextBox();
        personTextBox.ID = "textBox"+personID;
        textBoxes.add("textbox"+personID, personTextBox);
    }
```

I explain you:
first, I'm assuming there is an array of the personsIDs, so I created a dictionary (key -> value object) using strings as keys and TextBoxes as values.

then using a foreach I read all the personsID's, and for each one of them I create a new TextBox UIControl and add it to the dictionary using the personID as key. I also added its ID property as "textbox"+PersonID.

this way you can access your textboxes from code-behind by using your dictionary:

```
textBoxes["textbox"+personID] //(e.g: textBoxes['textBox11'])
```

but also, since your textBox.ID is equal to textbox+personID, you can also reference it after page has been rendered (e.g. using javascript).
now to add this controlers to your page, just use a container(UIControl) that already exists on your page, and use

```
container.controls.add(textbox);
```

this process can be expanded for extra elements, for instance:

1.- have a main placeholder already defined in your page:

```
<asp:Panel ID= "Panel1"  runat = "server">
```

2.- in your code-behind for each person create a new panel and add all the elements you want inside that panel:

```
//this goes inside your foreach
Panel innerPanel = new Panel();
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
Label label = new Label();

innerPanel.controls.add(textbox);
innerPanel.controls.add(label);
////
```

finally add your innerPanels in to your main panel:

```
panel1.controls.add(innerPanel);
```

so there you go, that's basically the idea, hope this helps.