# what is Difference between repeater and grid view?

Tags: asp.net

Any body please help me i want to show some records from database which is better grid view or repeater?  And u have more then 1000 rec**strong text**ord show on webpage

Comment: They're different, not better or worse: A **repeater** repeats *any* piece of output for each record, which needn't necessarily be tabular (think of business card view in Outlook, or a HTML `<ul>` list, anything really), while a **grid view** (as the name says) renders a tabular grid of columns and rows.

Comment: Neither I always prefer datalist. much more flexible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeater, ListView, DataList, DataGrid, GridView ... Which to choose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139207/repeater-listview-datalist-datagrid-gridview-which-to-choose)