# C# Make HTML Table repeating rows

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, sqldatareader

I have this HTML table:

```
<table ID="tbl_ClientSearch" style="width: 83%;" runat="server">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Client Account Number</td>
         <td>Client Name</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>                  
         <td><asp:Literal ID="CliNox" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>      
         <td><asp:Literal ID="CliNamex" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>            
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I have this query:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC [dbo].[CTLC_SearchClient] '" + SearchVal + "';");
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;
SqlDataReader readers = command.ExecuteReader();
if (readers.HasRows)
{
   while (readers.Read())
   {
      string CliNo = readers.GetString(0);
      string CliName = readers.GetString(1);
      CliNox.Text = string.Format("<a href='ClientInfo.aspx?ClientNumber={0}'>{0}</a>", CliNo.ToString());
      CliNamex.Text = CliName.ToString();
   }
   conn.Close();
}
```

This works but when I need to return multiple rows, this only returns 1 row since I only declared 1  for the table body. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your SP whether it returns more than one row or not?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid andeel Khalid Yes. It works fine. But the my program only shows the last row since I think it overwrites the value on the html table row.

Comment: i.e is write your program should show only last row, you have coded that way i.e you have only one <tr></tr> and you are overwriting that row cells, for your requirement you need to create table structure dynamically or simply use Gridview or repeater control.

Comment: Use a repeater control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx . Also your SQL Command is wide open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You can use, GridView, Repeater or asp:table to render mulitple rows in a table format.  Refer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/139308/405317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aspx page add placeholder apart from table like below.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "tableClientSearch" runat="server"/>
```

In Aspx.cs file.

```
 StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
                html.Append("<table border = '1'><thead><tr><td>Client Account 

Number</td><td>Client Name</td></tr></thead>");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC [dbo].[CTLC_SearchClient] '" + SearchVal + "';");
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        command.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataReader readers = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (readers.HasRows)
        {
            while (readers.Read())
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.AppendFormat("<a href='ClientInfo.aspx?ClientNumber={0}'>{0}</a>", readers.GetString(0));
                html.Append("</td>");
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(readers.GetString(1));
                html.Append("</td>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        html.Append("</table>");
        tableClientSearch.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

Comment: This will work. However, it is not a particularly great way to do it. Using a databound control would be a better option.

Comment: I agreed, i.e right this is not the great way to do it, but when the requirement is just to render table without any other functionality which provides by the databound controls i would prefer simple html controls which will definitely gain some small amount of performance.

Comment: just one more favor. how can I do the pagination of the table here? :) let's say 10 records per page

Comment: that you can implement by two ways., 1. client side:- if the table data is not going larger size and 2.Server side :- if your are not sure about data and there might be a chances to huge number of rows in table. based on that you have to decide approach.

Answer (score 1):

Delcare a protected table in aspx.cs file at class level

```
protected DataTable dt = new DataTable()
```

Fill this data table from sql query (by using DataAdapter), I guess you know how to do that, or just google it.

In aspx, replace

```
<tr>                  
    <td><asp:Literal ID="CliNox" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>      
    <td><asp:Literal ID="CliNamex" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>            
</tr>
```

by

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
{
    <tr>                  
        <td><%= dr["columnName1"] %></td>    
        <td><%= dr["columnName2"] %></td>            
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with asp.net, however this situation looks similar to some that could occur in php, in which case I would try generating the entire table in asp.  something along the lines of,

```
for row in tables
    append to html <tr><td>data</td><td>moredata</td></tr>

insert html into <table></table>
```